# define word boundaries for HTML5 spellcheck

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, spell-checking

I have some HTML in a `contenteditable` that looks like `<span>hello wor</span><strong>ld</strong></span>`. If I change it, so that `world` is misspelt, I would like to be able to get suggestions on this complete word. However, this is what actually happens:

[image]

The text is separated into two words, left clicking simply gives suggestions for one or the other.

Is there any recourse?

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of “spelling checks” requested by using the `spellcheck` attribute (which the question is apparently about) is heavily browser-dependent, and the HTML5 spec intentionally leaves the issue open. Browsers may implement whatever checks they like, the way they like, and they do. You cannot change this in your code.

Although modern browsers generally have spelling checks of some kind at least for English, they differ in the treatment of cases like this, among other things. Firefox treats adjacent inline elements (with no whitespace between them) as constituting one word, but Chrome and IE do not. Moreover, browsers might not spellcheck initial content, only content as entered or edited by the user.

The only way to get consistent spelling checking is to implement it yourself: instead of using the `spellcheck` attribute (“HTML5 spellcheck”), you would need to have spelling checking routine and integrate it into your HTML document using JavaScript. People who have implemented such systems normally have the routine running server-side and make the HTML page communicate with it using Ajax.